# find utility does not recognize bracket notation

Tags: shell, find, regular-expression, quoting

I've two files in the current folder:

> submitWeb.m
>   submit.m

the following `find` does not show the two files:

```
find . -regex .*submit\(Web\)?\.m
```

But the above regex expression works fine in emacs buffer, i.e., search for the example strings in the emacs buffer using `isearch-forward-regexp`.

The default `regextype` for `find` is `emacs`.

But it seems that `find` consider `\(` as a left bracket in the filename, which differs from emacs regex syntax.

So is this a bug or my misunderstanding of `find` manpage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is `\(` is interpreted by the shell first.

For example, you got a file in the current directory named:

> foo(.test

Then

```
ls foo\(.text
```

and

```
ls "foo(.text"
```

both work.

So, the following works:

```
find . -regex ".*submit\(Web\)?\.m"
```

**EDIT**:

Single quote also works here.

Difference between single quote and double quote, see this post: [single quote vs double quote in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Or put the regex in single quotes instead: `find . -regex '.*submit\(Web\)?\.m'`

Comment: @slm Yes, anyway, just prevent the shell from interpreting the `\(`. Edited.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to quote everything in single quotes unless you specifically need the substitution behavior of double quotes.